# How can an IAM role assume another IAM role to access an resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How to assume a role from another role in the same account.

Below is my first IAM role(roleA) to access sagemaker. one statement to allow access to sagemaker and another to allow assumerole.

```
statement {
    actions = [
      "sagemaker:*",
    ]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-1:1111111111:endpoint/ep",
    ]
  }

statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
  }
```

Now I have another IAM in the same AWS account(roleB).

```
    {
        "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/roleA"
    }
```

Now I assigned roleB to a Microservice. My understanding is Microservice should have access to sagemaker endpoint ep. But I am getting error that I don't have permission. where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you use the credentials associated with roleB to assume roleA? Did you then used the returned STS credentials associated with roleA to attempt to access allowed SageMaker resources?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you have to do something like the below in your `microservice`. As @jarmod already explained, you need to use the credentials and create clients.

```py
source_credentials = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=roleB_ARN,
        RoleSessionName=`session_name`,
    )
dest_sts_client = boto3.client(
    'sts',
    aws_access_key_id=source_credentials.get('Credentials').get('AccessKeyId'),
    aws_secret_access_key=source_credentials.get('Credentials').get('SecretAccessKey'),
    aws_session_token=source_credentials.get('Credentials').get('SessionToken')
)
dest_credentials = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn=roleA_ARN,
        RoleSessionName=`session_name`,
    )

sagemaker_client = boto3.client(
    'sagemaker',
    aws_access_key_id=dest_credentials.get('Credentials').get('AccessKeyId'),
    aws_secret_access_key=dest_credentials.get('Credentials').get('SecretAccessKey'),
    aws_session_token=dest_credentials.get('Credentials').get('SessionToken')
)
```

[AWS STS Role Chaining](https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/03/03/role-assumption-tricks.html)

[Roles terms and concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html)